# How to reverse engineer an NLP parse tree to arrive at the original sentence?

Tags: regex, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

Given a parse tree (obtained with http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process pretty print option)

```
(ROOT (S (NP (PRP You)) (VP (MD could) (VP (VB say) (SBAR (IN that) (S (NP (PRP they)) (ADVP (RB regularly)) (VP (VB catch) (NP (NP (DT a) (NN shower)) (, ,) (SBAR (WHNP (WDT which)) (S (VP (VBZ adds) (PP (TO to) (NP (NP (PRP$ their) (NN exhilaration)) (CC and) (NP (FW joie) (FW de) (FW vivre))))))))))))) (. .)))
```

How could I arrive at the original sentence?

```
You could say that they regularly catch a shower, which adds to their exhilaration and joie de vivre.
```

I am thinking of using some regexp magic, but I wonder if Stanford NLP has a built in feature to do this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert string to `Tree` using `Tree.fromstring()`. Now, you can use `Tree.leaves()` method to get all tokens from the tree.

**Code:**

```
from nltk import Tree

parse_str = "(ROOT (S (NP (PRP You)) (VP (MD could) (VP (VB say) (SBAR (IN that) (S (NP (PRP they)) (ADVP (RB regularly)) (VP (VB catch) (NP (NP (DT a) (NN shower)) (, ,) (SBAR (WHNP (WDT which)) (S (VP (VBZ adds) (PP (TO to) (NP (NP (PRP$ their) (NN exhilaration)) (CC and) (NP (FW joie) (FW de) (FW vivre))))))))))))) (. .)))"

t = Tree.fromstring(parse_str)

#print t.leaves()
print ' '.join(t.leaves())
```

**Output:**

```
You could say that they regularly catch a shower , which adds to their exhilaration and joie de vivre .
```

Comment: Thx @RAVI Looks like the output is tokenized? Could we get a non tokenized version as well?

Comment: As parse output don't store any non-tokenized sentence information, it is not possible to get that output.

Comment: However depending upon your requirement, you can write some rules based on token string to add space or not after toekn. For example, "," "." etc.

Answer (score 3):

Usually regular expressions aren't powerful enough to parse tree-like structures. If you wanted to parse this by hand the easiest way would probably be to write a small recursive descent parser, which would involve writing recursive functions that explore each node, where the functions for each leaf node would append to the result's text.

Luckily I don't think you will need to do any parsing since Stanford NLP has several ways to convert a tree to a `List` of leaves, and several ways to convert a `List` of leaves to a `Sentence`. See [these](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp-3.5.2/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.html) [links](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/Sentence.html). Specifically `Tree`'s `yield` methods could come in handy.

I would try `Sentence.listToOriginalTextString(tree.yield())`. If that doesn't work you could try `Sentence.listToOriginalTextString(taggedLabeledYield())`. The type signatures are a little awkward so I'm not 100% confident.